# Where can I find the adafruit_irremote GenericTransmit Address for Samsung?

Tags: python, adafruit-circuitpython

```
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 ladyada for Adafruit Industries
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

"""IR transmit example for Samsung TV using Circuit Playground Express"""
# pylint: disable-msg=no-member
import time
import pulseio
import board
import digitalio
import adafruit_irremote

# Create a button object to trigger IR transmit
button = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP0)
button.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
button.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN

pulseout = pulseio.PulseOut(board.GP1, frequency=38000, duty_cycle=2**15)
encoder = adafruit_irremote.GenericTransmit(
   header=[9500, 4500], one=[550, 550], zero=[550, 1700], trail=0
)

while True:
    if button.value:
        print("IR signal sent!")
        encoder.transmit(pulseout, [31, 31, 152, 103])
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Currently using the code above to attempt to transmit a simple power button press with the press of 'button'.

It runs the while loop without error, but nothing happens. I press the button and see the print statement, but nothing else. Where can I find the integers header, one, zero, and trail based on my TV. Documentation for the parameters is as follows:

header (int) – The length of header in microseconds

one (int) – The length of a one in microseconds

zero (int) – The length of a zero in microseconds

trail (int) – The length of the trail in microseconds, set to None to disable

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to control a Sony camera and I looked at the [Sony IRLib2 code](https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib2/blob/master/IRLibProtocols/IRLib_P02_Sony.h) for how to generate those for [cpx-ir-shutter-remote.py](https://github.com/kevinjwalters/circuitpython-examples/blob/master/cpx/cpx-ir-shutter-remote.py). There's [Samsung code](https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib2/blob/master/IRLibProtocols/IRLib_P08_Samsung36.h) in IRLib2 too which should be useful as a basis for your code.